# how to populate listview with multiple firebase items

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a social app for android 
I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase and display ( at least 15 items )
The problem is that my code displays just the first item 
this is  my code

FirebaseHelper

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
 DatabaseReference db;
 ArrayList<Questions> questionEntries =new ArrayList<>();
public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db)  {
    this.db=db;
    }

private void fetchData (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
questionEntries.clear();
    Questions questions = dataSnapshot.getValue(Questions.class);
    questionEntries.add(questions);}


public ArrayList<Questions> retreive (){
db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
return questionEntries;
}
```

this is my activity where the list is displayed

```
public class Actu extends Fragment {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_actu, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.actu_rv);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Questions");

    helper = new FirebaseHelper(db);
    adapter = new QuestionAdapter(getContext(),helper.retreive());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    return v;        }
}
```

[image: This my firebase database structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
public ArrayList<Questions> retreive (){
db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Questions questions = dataSnapshot.getValue(Questions.class);
    questionEntries.add(questions);

}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
```

Inside the `onChildAdded()` method you can retrieve the data of the children.

In the database you have `Question-KxOmo9FQ7QZMtq2wUIT`, Remove the **`Question`** from there and just keep the `id` there, this is like the `id` primary key in sql database, so you dont need `Question` here..

So remove the `fetchdata()` method.

Comment: Should i put the setText function again?

Comment: @user8773560 what `setText`, if its a listview then no dont use setText.. Also I updated the answer, should work now

Comment: I did it but it does not work. the result still the same (i'm getting only one element)

Comment: yes i did it. I have updated the database structure image there [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeYr9.png)